# Story with a man named Rush with Alzheimer's being guided by his AI through his day, and eventually using him to solve a murder

Tags: story-identification

I found the likely answer to [a deleted answer that was kind of a request for ID of another book](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/239548/23243) on [70's/80's Short story man uses PC to compensate for progressive memory loss then they die in suicide pact](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168799/70s-80s-short-story-man-uses-pc-to-compensate-for-progressive-memory-loss-then?rq=1) and I figured it was worth posting for if anyone else is looking for it.

> I remember one that's similar but I can't remember the title either! The first scene is him with his mother, watching her dying in bed of Alzheimer's and swearing to himself that he'll never go through that. The next scene is him waking up and the computer, his self-programmed AI, telling him the title of the song. His name is Rush. He is led through his days with the help of the AI,and the POV is wherever he goes, not the room. I vividly remember a cab ride and him removing things from his pockets so the AI can see what they are. It ends with the AI solving a murder, and having him build or get a bomb so he can kill the bad guy and himself at the same time at the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This matches up with Edward Wellen's *[Mind Slash Matter](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2177094.Mind_Slash_Matter)*

> A brilliant screenwriter is stricken with Alzheimer's disease. However, in anticipation of this he has prepared an intricate computer program to look after him and direct his every move. As a result he fools everyone, including the police, who suspect him of several slasher murders. While the screenwriter wanders ever closer to disaster, the computer diligently investigates events to find the real murderer.

The name of the protagonist is mentioned in [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/371169665?book_show_action=true):

> **Mind Slash Matter** is a unique entry into the world of mystery thrillers. The hero is a 2-time Oscar-winning screenwriter, Rush Lightbody, who is now a shell of his former self due to Alzheimer's. However, he is able to function due to a wonderful computer that he pre-programmed before the Alzheimer's set in that interacts with him by way of speakers, microphones, videocameras and pagers. Thus, Rush Lightbody is able to convince the outside world that he is still okay by way of a series prompts and firm instructions that come from the computer.

According to [this review](https://www.sffaudio.com/mind-slash-matter-by-edward-wellen-read-by-rene-a/)'s quote from the first chapter, it does open with him visiting his mother, who has full-blown Alzheimer's (and supporting by [the sample on Overdrive](https://www.overdrive.com/media/251536/mind-slash-matter)):

> *[His mother] should have died then, at that moment, but she lasted five terrible downhill years longer. Doctors were small help, they couldn’t cure or even treat Alzheimer’s. But they could tell him it seemed to run in families. So during those years, in between looking after her and meeting his deadlines, he put his mind to the matter of insuring that he would not end up mindless and helpless. That he would end up in the middle of a slasher case was farthest from his mind.*

I'm attempting to track down a copy to verify the other details.

Comment: Sounds like fun read